# Как решить проблему отображения русских букв в программе экслипс на эмуляторе андроид

Tags: java, android, кодировка

Суть такая, что при отправке сообщения, при помощи штатной программы эмулятора с одного эмулятора на другой вместо русских букв приходят кракозябры, когда пишешь сообщение английскими буквами все норм, кто сталкивался подскажите как решить проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это штатная ошибка эмулятора. Эмулятор [как известно](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3539), не умеет корректно посылать длинные сообщения.

Пошлите короткое сообщение из пары символов и все будет работать. Если хотите длинные - то тогда только хардкор - реальный девайс. Больше никак.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, теперь буду знать. Ну а так пробовал даже один русский символ отправить не работает. Значит на реальном устройстве программа сможет проанализировать русский текст в смс на совпадения с русским словом?